# How to direct users to a subcatalog

Tags: htaccess, directory

I have a home page at one.com (stolsvidda-loypelag.no) which is not made in WordPress. I have now installed WP on a subcatalog and developed new pages on this subcatalog (stolsvidda-loypelag.no/wordpress). 
How can a direct users to the new pages without deleting the old stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using .htaccess redirection rule.

Please try below redirection rule:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /index.html http://stolsvidda-loypelag.no/wordpress/index.html
```

**NOTE:** Here, I assume that your wordpress folder contains **index.html**